# Android L compiler prevents decompiling?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

As I heard in the last Google I/O the apps running on Android L will be compiled and run on the new ARM. So as far as I understood, will this prevent decompiling apps like it is possible right now? So that not everyone can decompile it and look into the source code?

Comment: I think you heard **very bad**. NOTHING is undecompilable.

Comment: Only the chosen ones will be able to do it...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein ok, i know that everything is in some way decompileable, but will the decompile process not be like extracting a zip/jar?

Comment: It has **NEVER** been like that

Comment: Dezipping an apk DOESN'T provide you with source code. And the xml files are mangled. And the 9.pngs are deprivated of their markers. You need a tool like `apktool` to **decompile** an apk. Then use something like `dex2jar` to get some **Java** code from the smali. And still you will get the method names like method_001 or such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android L will have the new ART. Apps will be compiled to native machine code on the device.

So, you are deploying a normal APK, but when the user installs it, it will be compiled to native machine code. I think, as long you can get the APK, decompilation will work fine, otherwise, if you cannot get it, you can still disassemble.

[ART](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html)